# Calcular sueldo liquido de una persona (Consola de JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy haciendo un curso de JavaScript pero me quede pegado en este problema que tengo que mostrar en consola `console.log(respuesta);`.

### El problema:

> **Ejercicio:**
>
> El sueldo líquido de un trabajador es de X pesos.
> Le mencionaron que le retuvieron el Y% de su sueldo bruto.
> Escriba una programa para calcular el sueldo Bruto acorde a las
> variables anteriormente mencionadas. (Ambas variables pueden
> tomar cualquier valor).
> En el caso que se ingrese una cantidad negativa para sueldo líquido
> (X) o retención (Y%), no se deberá aplicar la formula y por último se
> tendrá que indicar por consola que no es posible calcular.
> Sueldo líquido es la cantidad de dinero que finalmente va al bolsillo
> de cada trabajador, el sueldo bruto es el total de la remuneración
> recibida por el trabajador, antes de los descuentos pertinentes
> como cotizaciones previsionales o salud.
>
> =  í
>
> 1 − ó(%)

---

### Cómo he intentado resolverlo:

```html
 <script>
    var sueldoliquido = 1000000;
    retencion = 20%;
    sueldobruto = 1000000;
    sueldobruto = sueldoliquido / 1 - retencion;
    console.log(sueldobruto);


</script>
```

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: Y cual es el problem con tu codigo?

Comment: El problema esta en que no me da el resultado en la consola creo que estoy usando una mala formula o no sabría de que forma plantearlo para que resulte.

Comment: imposible ver tu codigo en la foto.. que resultado te da? que resultado deberia darte?

Comment: el codigo, como te puse en el primer comentario, va en la pregunta... todo, va en la pregunta. usar el boton [edit]. y arregla la pregunta... asi todos podemos ayudarte...

Comment: y entonces, porque mostras por consola el sueldoliquido en lugar del sueldobruto?

Comment: y lee sobre precendencia de operadores.. sin parentesis, esa consulta devuelve cualquier cosa ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript no maneja porcentajes de esa manera, *%* es un operador que no tiene nada que ver con porcentaje.

Tendrías que reescribir tu código de esta manera:

```
    var sueldoliquido = 1000000;
    retencion = 20;
    sueldobruto = sueldoliquido / (1 - retencion / 100);
    console.log(sueldobruto);
```

Creo que en definitiva es la solución que buscas. Para hacer un ejercicio; si el sueldo líquido es de 1000000 entonces el sueldo bruto será 1250000, es razonable.

Comment: tenes razon... lenguaje equivocado por mi...

Comment: @gbianchi no hay problema amigo, también me he equivocado en muchas ocasiones.

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado

Comment: @BryanJoséM79 no hay problema!

Answer (score -1):

A la hora de mostrar deberías mostrar el `sueldobruto` que es tu resultado.

```html
<script>
        var sueldoliquido = 1000000;
        retencion = 0.20;
        sueldobruto = 1000000;
        sueldobruto = sueldoliquido / (1 - retencion);
        console.log(sueldobruto);


    </script>
```

Comment: sueldoliquido / 1 es nada...

Comment: *Liquido* es "neto", así que lo normal es que el líquido sea el resultado de quitar el 20% al bruto

Comment: @gbianchi toda la razón, en la segunda edición vi la formula.

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado